# Помогите с запростом Mysql

Tags: mysql

делаю фильтры, У МЕНЯ ТАКОЙ запрос,

```
SELECT `product`.* 
FROM `product` 
LEFT JOIN `item2cat` ON `product`.`id` = `item2cat`.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN `category` ON `item2cat`.`category_id` = `category`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `property_value_product` ON `product`.`id` = `property_value_product`.`idProduct` 
WHERE (`product`.`status`=1) 
  AND (`category`.`id` IN ('4', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '5', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '50', 1)) 
  AND (`property_value_product`.`idValue`=2) 
  AND (`property_value_product`.`idValue`=34)
```

по идее должен выбирать товары у которых в таблице property_value_product записаны их айди  в поле idProduct и в поле idValue записано 2 и 34
то есть у одного продукта есть 2 записи к примеру 100 2 и 100 34
причем работает нормально только если убрать `AND (property_value_product.idValue=34)`
тогда ищет все у которых idValue=2
а если надо чтоб у товара было и idValue=2 и idValue=34 (то есть 2 записи такие есть в таблице)
он не ищет, что не так делаю, подскажите, плиз.

Comment: *что не так делаю* Все условия из WHERE применяются к ОДНОЙ ЗАПИСИ. Вы требуете, чтобы поле `property_value_product.idValue` было одновременно равно и 2, и 34. А такого не бывает. Посему и результат пустой.

Comment: Проще всего - убрать property_value_product из FROM и переписать на два WHERE EXISTS.

Comment: не можете пример привести? я просто еще этот запрос средствами yii формирую, но хотя бы имея сырой mysql рабочий, смогу уже решить проблему.

Comment: я как понял надо убрать join property_value_product  так? Если не сложно, прямо мой код поправьте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте:

```
SELECT `product`.* 
FROM `product` 
INNER JOIN `item2cat` ON `product`.`id` = `item2cat`.`product_id` 
INNER JOIN `category` ON `item2cat`.`category_id` = `category`.`id` 
WHERE `product`.`status` = 1
  AND `category`.`id` IN ('4', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '5', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '50', 1)
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM `property_value_product`
               WHERE `product`.`id` = `property_value_product`.`idProduct`
                 AND `idValue` = 2 ) 
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM `property_value_product`
               WHERE `product`.`id` = `property_value_product`.`idProduct`
                 AND `idValue` = 34 )
```

Comment: Ошибка в запросe (1064): Syntax error near 'ON `product`.`id` = `property_value_product`.`idProduct` AND `' at line 9

Comment: вот что пишет  такую ошибку

Comment: Посмотрите, плиз, что не так может быть.

Comment: @zemlia-zemlia Упс. Недопоправил. Ща... готово.

Comment: Спасибо! Проверил, синтаксис ок, но выбрало 13...

Comment: @zemlia-zemlia *но выбрало 13* Вот этой фразы откровенно не понял...

Comment: А все разобрался. Надо еще Group by добавить, а то он некоторые выводит по 2 раза. Если есть способ лучше чем группировать, поправьте, плиз, а так я в ответ допишу этот груп бай. Спасибо огромное вам, очень выручили.

Comment: @zemlia-zemlia *Если есть способ лучше чем группировать, поправьте, плиз* Конечно, есть. Не использовать звезду, перечислить список конкретных полей конкретных таблиц, которые РЕАЛЬНО нужны. Если при этом выводятся полные дубликаты - использовать DISTINCT, если дубликаты по некоторым, не всем, полям, но надо только одну запись - группировать по полям-дубликатам и применять групповые функции к остальным полям.

Comment: @zemlia-zemlia Правка - отклонена. В нынешний вид запроса НЕЛЬЗЯ просто добавить GROUP BY - это приводит к синтаксически ошибочному запросу. К тому же противоречит тексту запроса в вопросе.

Comment: Да все поля нужны, тут на yii записи сразу объектами становятся, никак без всех полей. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: А у меня работает корректно

Comment: @zemlia-zemlia А установи SQL Mode = `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` - и всё, конец твоей "корректности".

Comment: нет синтаксических ошибок, сейчас еще погоняю побольше, но как группировку добавил стало корректно. насчет 13 вывело я не дописал, в базе в общем 9 товаров у которых и 2 и 34 а вывело сначала 13 а с группировкой 9. Может быть поправите как правильно тогда? Просто я пишу на yii и там не надо думать как sql работает, и я таких тонкостей не знаю, типа  DISTINCT и прочего что вы писали выше, скажу лишь только что да, все поля нужны, они в дальнейшем используются. и их приджойненых таблиц тоже.

Comment: насчет SQL Mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY это да, но у меня вообще с таким режимом не заработает сам yii - сталкивался, где то был установлен, тоже искал в чем проблема. Но поправьте тогда запрос, чтоб корректно работало и правильно было, людям поможет потом.

Comment: @zemlia-zemlia надеюсь, Вы понимаете, что без группировки есть две (или больше) записи с одинаковым, скажем, product.id, но разными category.id. После группировки останется одна запись. product.id в ней будет какой надо. А вот какой один из нескольких category.id - это никто не предскажет... Впрочем, Вы же берёте только из `product` данные... тогда не `GROUP BY`, а вульгарно `SELECT DISTINCT product.*`.

Comment: Да, понимаю, у меня один товар может в несколько категорий входить, но да, на данном этапе это не важно, главное что бы он входил в одну из перечисленных в массиве. В общем с DISTINCT  тогда оставлю, тоже корректно работает. Спасибо!!!

Comment: @zemlia-zemlia Лучше именно DISTINCT - он побыстрее, и ресурсов съест меньше по сравнению с GROUP BY.